# Sending a file using jQuery and Ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax, post

I have this code that is supposed to select a file and then send it with a POST api, the file is going to be an excel file. This is my first time trying to send a file through an api and I am not having much luck. I am able to get the file when its selected, and the put it in the formData. My problem is the contentType with the api call. So first, here is the code that gets the file and adds it to the formData. Now, the api is looking for an array inside an object which is why I add the formdata to the array and send postData as the parameter.

```
 let fileName;
 let file = [];
 let form = new FormData()

$("#commodityAH_massEdit").on("click", function () {
        $('#loadHolidayModal').modal('show');
      });

      $('#myFile').change(function(e){
        fileName = $("#myFile").prop('files')[0];
        console.log("the file selected is", fileName);
    })

      $("#btn-massEdit").on("click", function () {
        form.append('filename', fileName, fileName.name );
        file.push(form)
        let postData = {
          filename: file
        }

       $.fn.updateSupplier(postData)
          .then(res => {
            console.log("keys length", Object.keys(res).length)
            if (res != undefined && Object.keys(res).length > 0) {
              selectCommodities = [];
              $('#massEditModal').modal('hide');
              $('#message-massedit').text('');
              $("#successMassEdit").find('.message').html('Supplier updated successfully!');
              $('#successMassEdit').modal('show');
              Self.initTable();
            } else {
              selectCommodities = [];
              $('#massEditModal').modal('hide');
              $('#message-massedit').text('');
              $("#messageMassFail").find('.message').html('Supplier Failed to update!');
              $('#messageMassFail').modal('show');
              console.error(res);
            }
          })
          .catch(err => {
            console.error('update Supplier err', err);
          })
      });
```

Then here is the api.

```
 $.fn.updateSupplier = function (postData) {
        console.log("the post data being sent is", postData)
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
          $.ajax({
              type: "POST",
              url: "https://admin-business.azurewebsites.net/api/uploadBusinessSupplies",
              dataType:  JSON.stringify(postData),
              processData: false,
              contenType: multipart/form-data,
              headers: {
                jwt: $.cookie("jwt")
              }
            })
            .done(function (res) {
              resolve(res);
            })
            .fail(function (err) {
              reject(err);
            });
        })
    }
```

The contentType seems to be the issue here. I have done some research, and in some examples they had the both the processData, and contentType set to false. When I set the contentType to false and jdon I get this

[image: json and false contentType error]

After that did not work I tried setting the content type to multipart/form-data, and then I also tried setting it to json and stringifying the postData. For setting the contentType to json I get the same Malformed error, and then for the multipart/form-data I get this error . Any help would be greatly appreciated

[image: multipart/form-data content type error]

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. I do not see where you are using AJAX nor do I see where you submit the FormData. Please provide a Minimal, Reproducible Example: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Your pictures are the same. Also please post the actual text of the errors: https://www.google.com/search?q=multipart+boundary+not+found+site:stackoverflow.com

Comment: @mplungjan I changed it to include the entire error

Comment: @Twisty you can see the post ajax is the api call in the second part of the post. Theres also inside of  $("#btn-massEdit").on("click", function () you can see the formdata append the file, gets put in an array and gets set to filename for the api. Then the function calls the api with postData passed to it

Comment: @Ash_c it's still not clear where `updateSupplier` is defined in relationship to your other code. It's hard for anyone to help if we are unable to replicate the issue or event test it.

Comment: The 500 Error indicates an issue with your Code on the server, your back-end code. 500 is a status that is used when the server is configured to not display errors from the scripts, basically "general error", but it can say more. Please check your server logs.